# How do I accept integers and strings all at once in python

Tags: python

Wanted input is something like this:

Sam, 100, Josh, 200, Adam, 150 and so on...

With comma and space separating each one.

And then after accepting the input I need to calculate the average of these numbers.

I **cannot** use functions nor the function `map()`, which could be very helpful in this situation.

This is what I got so far although I think it's very far from being right. I need only one input but I was able to do it only with multiple inputs.

```
n = int(input())
mynames = list()
scores = list()
for i in range(n):
    name = input()
    mynames += [name]
    for j in range(len(mynames)):
        scores +=  [int(name.split(',')[1])]
        
print(sum(scores)/n)
```

Thank you!

Comment: So inputting how many n (names + values) to insert, and then inputting the data will be considered as having multiple inputs? In that case, you can input every data you need in one go and then only do the splitting and calculation?

Comment: Um, if you can't use functions then that means no `input()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the usage of list, it can save you a lot of time and effort. For instance, let's say you are inputting all the data in one go.

```
print('Please insert all the required data:\n')
mydata = input()

split_result = mydata.split(',')

mynames = split_result[0::2]
scores = [float(i) for i in split_result[1::2]]

average = sum(scores)/len(scores)

print (mynames)
print (scores)
print(average)
```

This is what you will get instantly.

```
Please insert all the required data:

Sam, 100, Josh, 200, Adam, 150
['Sam', ' Josh', ' Adam']
[100.0, 200.0, 150.0]
150.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to have `[Sam, Josh, Adam, ...]` in mynames and `[100, 200,  150, ...]` in scores

And as it seems it's ok to use split()

```py
n = int(input())
mynames = list()
scores = list()
input_str = input()
input_str_split = input_str.split(', ')
for i in range(n):
    mynames.append(input_str_split[i*2])
    scores.append(int(input_str_split[i*2+1]))
print(sum(scores)/n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of you Problem :

```
n = input()
myarray = n.split(',')
scores = []
sumOfScores = 0
studentname = []
for i in range(len(myarray)):
    if((i+1)%2 == 0):
        scores.append(int(myarray[i]))
    else: 
        studentname.append(myarray[i])
        

# Finding Sum of scores
for i in scores:
    sumOfScores += i;

print(sumOfScores)
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use functions then you will have to use a very lineair method:

scanning each character from the input and remembering what you have read.

```
input_string = 'Sam, 100, Josh, 200, Adam, 150'

mynames = []
myscores = []

name = ''
score = ''
read_characters = ''
for character in input_string:
    if character == ',':
        # new part detected
        if not name:
            # this must be a name
            name = read_characters
            read_characters = ''
        else:
            # name already read, this must be a value
            score = read_characters

            mynames.append(name)
            myscores.append(score)

            # start with a new name-value pair
            name = ''
            score = ''
            read_characters = ''
    else:
        # collect read characters untill a comma is read
        read_characters += character

# if the input is not ending with a comma, there can be a last name-value pair
# save the last values
if name and read_characters:
    mynames.append(name)
    myscores.append(read_characters)

print(mynames)
print(myscores)

i = 0
scores_sum = 0
for score in myscores:
    scores_sum += int(score)
    i += 1

print(scores_sum / i)
```

Output

```
['Sam', ' Josh', ' Adam']
[' 100', ' 200', ' 150']
150.0
```

If you can't even use the append function and are only interested in the average then you can also calculate the average during parsing.

```
input_string = 'Sam, 100, Josh, 200, Adam, 150'

scores_sum = 0
nr_of_scores = 0

name = ''
score = ''
read_characters = ''
for character in input_string:
    if character == ',':
        # new part detected
        if not name:
            # this must be a name
            name = read_characters
            read_characters = ''
        else:
            # name already read, this must be a value
            score = read_characters

            print(name, score)
            scores_sum += int(score)
            nr_of_scores += 1

            # start with a new name-value pair
            name = ''
            score = ''
            read_characters = ''
    else:
        read_characters += character

# if the input is not ending with a comma, there can be a last name-value pair
# save the last values
if name and read_characters:
    print(name, read_characters)
    scores_sum += int(read_characters)
    nr_of_scores += 1

print(scores_sum / nr_of_scores)
```

The only function remaining is the conversion int() which could be not be replaced without using other functions like ord(). So I guess here stops replacing functions by mere code.